# How do I refer to attributes with dollar signs in the name in jq?

Tags: json, jq

I have some JSON:

```
{
  "Data": {
    "$id": "1",
    "voters": {
      "$id": "2",
      "$values": [
        {
          "$id": "3",
          "voterStatus": 0,
          "voterStatusName": "Active",
          "statusReasonName": "Registered",
          "voterTypeName": "Regular"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "Success": true,
  "ErrorMessage": null,
  "WarningMessage": null
}
```

I want the value of voterStatus.  I have tried `.Data.voters.$values[0].voterStatus`, but I get the following error:

```
$ jq </tmp/Voter.json '.Data.voters.$values[0].voterStatus'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1: .Data.voters.$values[0].voterStatus
jq: 1 compile error
$
```

1. What expression do I need to use to get the value of voterStatus?
2. How do I get the value of `.Data.$id`, which is '1' in the above sample?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

From [Object Identifier-Index: .foo, .foo.bar](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#object-identifier-index) in the jq manual:

> If the key contains special characters or starts with a digit, you
> need to surround it with double quotes like this: ."foo$", or else
> .["foo$"].
>
> For example .["foo::bar"] and .["foo.bar"] work while .foo::bar does
> not.

So:

```
$ jq '.Data.voters."$values"[0].voterStatus' file.json
0
```

and

```
$ jq '.Data."$id"' file.json
"1"
```